# Downloading data directly to volatile memory

Tags: networking, ram

When you download a file from the internet whether it be a FTP request, a Peer to Peer connection, ext. you are always prompted with a window asking where to store the file on your HDD or SSD, maybe you have a little NAS enclosure in your house.. either way you put it this information is being stored to a physical drive and the information is not considered volatile. It is stored digitally or magnetically and readily available to you even after the system is restarted.

Is it *possible* for software to be programmed to download and store information directly to a designated location in RAM without it ever touching a form of non-volatile memory?

If this is not possible can you please elaborate on why?

Otherwise if this is possible, if you could give me examples of software that implement this, or perhaps a scenario where this would be the only resolution to generate a desired outcome?

Thank you for the help. I feel this must be possible, however, I cant think of anytime I've encountered this and google doesn't seem to understand what I'm asking.

**edit:** This is being asked from the perspective of a novice programmer; someone who is looking into creating something like this. I seem to have over-inflated my own question. I suppose what I mean to ask is as follows:

> How is software such as RAMDisk programmed, how exactly does it work, and are heavily abstract languages such as C# and Java incapable of implementing such a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not very hard to do if I understand your request correctly. What you're looking for is `tmpfs`[1].

Carve our a `tmpfs` partition (if /tmp isn't `tmpfs` for you by default), mount it at a location, say something like `/volative`.

Then you can simply configure your browser or whatever application to download all files to folder/directory henceforth. Since `tmpfs` is essentially ram mounted as a folder, it's reset after reboot.

**Edit**: OP asks for how `tmpfs` and related ram based file systems are implemented. This is something that is usually Operating system specific, but the general idea probably remains the same: The driver responsible for the ram file system `mmap()` the required amount of memory and then exposes that memory in a way file system APIs typical to your operating system (For example POSIX-y operations on linux/solaris/bsd) can access it.

Here's a [paper describing the implemention of tmpfs on solaris](http://www.solarisinternals.com/si/reading/tmpfs.pdf)[2]

**Further note**: If however you're trying to simply download something, use it and delete it without ever hitting disk in a way that's internal entirely to your application, then you can simply allocate memory dynamically based on the size of whatever you're downloading, write bytes into allocated memory and `free()` it once you're done using it.

---

This answer assumes you're on a Linux-y operating system. There are likely similar solutions for other operating systems.

---

References:

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs

[2] http://www.solarisinternals.com/si/reading/tmpfs.pdf

Comment: Hm.. seems as though I myself didn't even understand quite what I was trying to ask until realizing you're describing something like RAMDisk.. please see my edit for the correct rewording.

Comment: @CorderroArtz Yes, RAMDisk is at least in spirit the same thing `tmpfs` is, you could say `tmpfs` is a type of [RAM Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive). As to your edit, well something like a new filesystem type is usually implement at the operating system level or using userspace APIs the OS exposes to specifically to extend such functionality. Which language you use to implement is immaterial as long as your language lets you access those OS APIs.